# How to avoid nested mapply in R

Tags: r

I'm aware that nested lapply functions can be replaced by rapply as shown below

For a 3 level nested list :

```
lapply(data,function(x) lapply(x,function(x) lapply(x,function(x)funca(x))))
```

is equivalent to

```
rapply(data, function(x) sum(x),how = "list")
```

PS :Correct me if my understanding about lapply and rapply is wrong

#

Now I have a scenario where I have to write mapply for same 3 level nested list as shown below

```
mapply(function(x,y) mapply(function(x,y) mapply(function(x,y) funcb(x,y),x,y),x,y),data1,data2,SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

can I replace it with single mapply (i.e) does mapply have the inherent property of rapply or Is there any other equivalent function available

I tried replacing it with single mapply, it gave me, a slightly different result at few values in the resultant list. Just want to clarify about the same

#

Input list 1:(3 level nested list)

```
[[1]]
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1]   1 128 177  82  18 156   1

[[1]][[2]]
[1]   1 142  65 141 107 143   1

[[1]][[3]]
[1]   1 179  92  34 194 171   1

[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1]   1 128 177  82  18 156   1

[[2]][[2]]
[1]   1 142  65 141 107 143   1

[[2]][[3]]
[1]   1 179  92  171   1


[[2]]
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1]   1 128 177   156   1

[[1]][[2]]
[1]   1  107 143   1

[[1]][[3]]
[1]   1 179  92  34 194 171   1

[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1]   1 128 177  82  18 156   1

[[2]][[2]]
[1]   1 142  107 143   1

[[2]][[3]]
[1]   1 179  92  34 194 171   1
```

#### #

Input list 2(3 level nested list)(same structure as list1)

```
[[1]]
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1]   120.8

[[1]][[2]]
[1]   192.7

[[1]][[3]]
[1]   992

[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1]   895

[[2]][[2]]
[1]   220

[[2]][[3]]
[1]   440


[[2]]
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1]   203

[[1]][[2]]
[1]   404

[[1]][[3]]
[1]   20.35

[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1]   45.6

[[2]][[2]]
[1]   56.93

[[2]][[3]]
[1]   99.3
```

Function to performed using the above list is something  like, say if length of 
(1 128 177  82  18 156   1) is less than a constant number say(7), then reduce the corresponding value (120.8) in list 2  by 10% or something

Output structure should be similar to input structure

Comment: Create a recursive function for `mapply`.  Please provide a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: Hi akrun, Please let me know if you need any further clarification on the expected output

Comment: I did a nested mapply, as mentioned above. Just want to know if there is better way to do it

Comment: Please use `dput(...)` to show your data.